# Finding and following symbolic links but without deleting them

Tags: linux, bash, unix, find, symlink

The current find command is utilized to find and delete outdated files and directories. The expired data is based on a given properties file and the destination.
If the properties file says…

"/home/some/working/directory;.;180"

…then we want files and empty subdirectories deleted after 180 days.
The original command is…

"find ${var[0]} -mtime +${var[2]} -delete &"

…but I now need to modify now that we've discovered is has deleted symbolic links that existed in specified sub-directories after the given expiration date in the properties file. The variable path and variable expiration time are designated in the properties file (as previously demonstrated).

I have been testing using…

"find -L"

…to follow the symbolic links to make sure this clean up command reaches the destinations, as desired.
I have also been testing using…

"\! -type l"

…to ignore deleting symbolic links, so the command I've been trying is…

"find -L ${var[0]} ! -type l -mtime +${var[2]} -delete &"
…but I haven't achieved the desired results. Help please, I am still fresh into Linux and my research hasn't lead me to a desired answer. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
\! -type l
```

to

```
\! -xtype l
```

```
    find -L ${var[0]} \\! -xtype l -mtime +${var[2]} -delete &
```